# c# char.GetNumericValue returns -1

Tags: c#, char

I've got the following code that should find the hidden key in text.

```
private static string FindKey(string text)
{
    int keyLength = text[0];
    int[] keySliced = new int[keyLength];
    char[] fullText = text.ToCharArray();
    char[] chars = new char[text.Length - (1 + keyLength)];

    Console.WriteLine("Key Length -> {0}", keyLength);

    int y = 0;
    for(int i = 1 + chars.Length; i < 1 + chars.Length + keyLength; i++)
    {
        char chr = fullText[i];
        keySliced[y] = Convert.ToInt32(char.GetNumericValue(chr));
        Console.WriteLine("Key[{0}] -> {1}", y, keySliced[y]);
        y++;
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I run this code it returns something like this

```
Input: 5SampleText42964
Result:
Key[0] -> 4
Key[1] -> 2
Key[2] -> 9
Key[3] -> 6
Key[4] -> -1 //Here is the problem

Expected Result:
Key[0] -> 4
Key[1] -> 2
Key[2] -> 9
Key[3] -> 6
Key[4] -> 4
```

The Key[4] value is always -1 but it shouldn't

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx).  The method returns `"The numeric value of c if that character represents a number; otherwise, -1.0."`.  Without knowing your input this will be pretty hard to answer.  Your question must include a [MCVE]

Comment: `int keyLength = text[0];` is returning the ASCII value of the character at index `0` in the string. `int keyLength = Convert.ToInt32(text[0]);` would give you the numeric value of the character converted to an integer (or will throw an exception if the conversion fails)

Comment: Your code won't even compile, much less give you the results you claim it gives.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't compile. You have to actually return a `string`. And when you fix that, then you get an overflow error. So why don't you start by posting the actual code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It would *also* help if you defined *why* your expected result is expected. In other words, describe how is your algorithm *supposed* to work, and give more than one piece of sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted a complete example in your question, so my answer is purely a guess.

You could *really* simplify your logic by using LINQ:

```
//Assuming you have already checked the 'text' variable
//to make sure its not null or empty
int keyLength = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(text[0]);

if(keyLength < 0)
{
    //keyLength is -1 because the first digit was not a number
    //Handle appropriately
}
char[] keySliced = text.ToCharArray()
                       .Skip(1)
                       .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x))
                       .Take(keyLength)
                       .ToArray();
```

What this LINQ does is takes the input string and turns it into a char array (`.ToCharArray()`).  Then we skip the first character (`.Skip()`) because we have already accounted for that in the keyLength logic.  Then we only care about chars that are digits (`.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x))`).  Then we take up to the keyLength amount (`.Take(keyLength)`).  Not that this will take the chars in order, and only up to the amount specified in the *very first digit of the string* (so an input that is `"53dad223sfd32"` would not take `53` but `5`).  Then it looks like you want the results in a char array so we just materialize into an array (`.ToCharArray()`)

`keySliced` will now be a char array containing all the numbers up to the length you define as the first char in the string.

For input of: `"5SampleText42964"`

Results in:

```
Key[0] -> 4
Key[1] -> 2
Key[2] -> 9
Key[3] -> 6
Key[4] -> 4
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FhSVrL)

Comment: Oh, really thanks for this answer! It's now working correctly!

Comment: Note that for sample data `"5We8The7SlicesIn1HourAnd45Minutes12345"` the result will be `{ 8, 7, 1, 4, 5 }`. Not saying that's wrong, just not sure how you know what the expected result is.

Comment: @RufusL yeah I took a stab at the expected result.  I explained the LINQ logic in basic terms so if it matched what OP wanted they would know.  I likely shouldn't have even answered a question without having a clear expected result but I took a stab anyway